# 2d array issue with inputting correct values

Tags: c#, matrix

What I'm trying to do is create a rolling dice program where i have 1000 n-sided dice. n being 6,8,10, up to 20 in increments of 2. While rolling the dice I keep track of how many times that sided die lands on 1. I then decrease my total amount of dice for the corresponding sides by the amount of ones I rolled, until I have less dice than the amount of sides. I understand what I need to do, I'm just struggling to code it.

`diceM[1,1] through diceM[1,8]` holds 1000. The started amount of dice where the second number in the 2d array locates which n-sided die I am working with.

Okay here is my code at the moment.

```
static void RollDice()
{
  Random dice = new Random();
  int sides = 6;
  int row = 1, col = 1;
  while (diceM[row, col] >= sides && sides <= 20)
  {
    for (int k = 1; k <=8; k++)
    {
      int ones = 0;
      for (int i = 1; i <= diceM[row, col]; i++)
      {
        int value = dice.Next(1, sides + 1);
        if (value == 1)
          ones++;
      }
      diceM[row + 1, col] = diceM[row, col] - ones;
      sides += 2;
      row++;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm struggling on deciding where to loop to increment the columns and rows of the matrix to keep track of which n-sided dice I am rolling and where to keep track of how many times I have rolled overall.

Comment: Indexing starts at 0, not 1.  Could you show were you create `diceM`?

Comment: First I want to make sure I understood your question right. You have 1000 dice with 6 sides and 1000 with 8 sides...and totally you have 8000 dice right?

Comment: I suppose that's right. The way I look at it is... first I have a 6 sided die, I will roll it 1000 times. Then next I have an 8 sided die, and I will roll it 1000. etc.

Comment: Do you really need a matrix for this problem? It seems like it would be much simpler to put each dice type into its own array/vector. Simplicity is your friend.

Comment: yes i have to use a matrix for this